# SQL Server query sub subtraction

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a Ledger table see the image

I want to write a query which will subtract DR-CR data.. and requrn only due amount data.

its should omitted the paid amount 5000 because we have 2000 on 1-3-2014  and 3000 on 1-4-2014

can you please help... I have done this on application . But I want to do this on my sql query. 
  [image]

Comment: Why not omit the two `$1000` values instead of the single `$2000`?  Either of those combined with the `$3000` will be `$5000`

Comment: Because its a ledger calculation . when some one pay it will adjust with past due first... thats why 2000 and 3000 omitted

Comment: Shouldn't there be a field to indicate the account or something like that?  Also, what if the payment was 1000?  What would be the desired output then?

Comment: My question is how are you determining that you are going to use the $2000 instead of the two $1000 amounts?  I'm sure it makes sense to you, but you haven't specified to us how that decision is made

Comment: @AbeMiessler, the decision is made by going in Date order ascending.   At least that's how I took his answer.  However, Dan's question still needs to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008 doesn't have a cumulative sum.  So, you have to use more complicated expressions.  The idea is to take the cumulative amount of DR, then subtract the sum of the credit, and choose the rows where the value is positive.

```
select l.*
from (select l.*,
             (select sum(dr)
              from ledger l2
              where l2.id <= l.id
             ) as cumdr,
             sum(cr) over () as sumcr
      from ledger l
     ) l
where cumdr - sumcr > 0;
```